# Is there any way to throw your weapon and then teleport to its position?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, teleportation, throwing-things

I'm building a bladesinger who dual-wields scimitars. I'm taking 3 levels in Eldritch Knight for the ability to throw them and teleport them back.

Is there any race, feat, enchantment, anything, which allows you to teleport to the space where your weapon is (if it's not locked in a tiny chest or something), preferably appearing with it in your hand?

Comment: Hi Andy, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [tour] to see how our site works, and when you reach 20 rep, you'll be able to join us in [chat].

Comment: Have you been playing Final Fantasy 15? That is pretty much the power the main character has.

Comment: Why not just cast Misty Step and "fluff" that he's throwing a dagger and teleporting to it?

Answer (score 19):

## Yes

There are options available to you as a Wizard (BladeSinger/Eldritch Knight) that will allow you to throw your weapon and 'teleport' to it's location.

There are also several pieces of information that will be useful to you with regard to how to do this that I will outline below.

1. ***Throwing your weapon*** - Under Improvised Weapons (PHB 148), there is direction for providing ranged attacks/throwing melee weapons that don't have the ranged property. These rules can be used for attempting to hit a specific space.

   > If a character uses a ranged weapon to make a melee attack, or throws a melee weapon that does not have the thrown property, it also deals 1d4 damage. An improvised thrown weapon has a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet.

**Note:** Your DM may run it differently for how to throw your weapon (action cost, range, etc), but this gives some potential guidance to that conversation.

2. ***"Teleporting"*** - Here's where it gets more interesting. The options aren't immense, but there are some available to you that allow to "move" from your current position to the position you've thrown your weapon. They include:

   1. **Misty Step - 2nd level spell, 30' range you can see, bonus action to cast.** This may be your best option - especially if your DM requires an action to accurately throw your weapon.
   2. **Dimension Door - 4th level spell, 500', Action to cast.** This spell gives you significantly more range and capability, but it takes an action and a higher level spell slot.
   3. **Teleport - 7th level spell, anywhere, action to cast.** There are some other requirements as well, but given the high cost of this, I don't think it's what you're looking for.
   4. **Helm of Teleportation - Rare magic item.** This helm gives you up to 3 Teleport castings/day.
   5. **Cape of the Mountebank - Rare magic item.** This cape allows for one cast of Dimension Door/day.
   6. **Ring of Spell Storing - Rare magic item.** If you can cast Misty Step, you could have two safely stored in the ring for use without expending any spell slots.
   7. **6 class level dip into Monk - Way of the Shadow** Given that you're already multiclassing into Fighter, such a deep dip into another class likely isn't reasonable. If you do it, then you would be able to use Shadow Step (PHB 80) to 'teleport' from shadow to shadow (dim light/darkness) up to 60' a bonus action AND get advantage on your first melee attack you make before the end of the turn.

Once you are in the space that contains your weapon, you have a couple of ways to pick it up: Either through a Free Action (PHB 190.) **Please note** that if you have misty-stepped to the location, you no longer have a bonus action available to summon the weapon to you.

### But why?

When figuring out how to do this, please also think about the why. Roleplay is an excellent reason, but many of the ways to do this are an expenditure of limited resources to do something you can generally do by moving. That decision to do so is absolutely fine, but consider why you're trying to do something as well as how to do it.

Comment: "There aren't a lot of rules around how far you can throw an object, but you can take the range information from thrown weapons as some guidance. " The rules are pretty clear here: "If a character uses a ranged weapon to make a melee attack, or throws a melee weapon that does not have the thrown property, it also deals 1d4 damage. An improvised thrown weapon has a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet."

Comment: @Doval Thank you! I still think there may be a difference between trying to hit a creature in a space (a ranged attack) vs just throwing into a space and left my note - but this definitely helps. Much Appreciated!

Comment: There isn't. Step 1 of Making An Attack: *"Choose a target. Pick a target within your attack’s range: a creature, an object, or a location."* The rules don't change if you're attacking a location (which might contain a hidden creature). The only part of the process that requires the DM to make a judgment call is how far a weapon or ammunition continues to fly if it misses its target. Usually you can hand-wave the location of ammunition but the location of thrown weapons tends to become relevant very quickly.

Comment: @Doval Ah! That's a very good point. I guess targeting a space is targeting a space. I still think there's some room for DM fiat there (isn't there always?), but most would utilize this system of 20/60.

Answer (score 7):

Is there a game effect that you are trying to achieve, or is this mainly cinematic impressiveness?  If the latter, I'd say just throw the weapon to any clear space within 30', *Misty Step* (bonus action) to where you threw it, and catch it, and use it.  Or use the similar ability of a Shadow Monk.  As a DM, I'd let you do that; it isn't appreciably different in game mechanics than just teleporting while holding your weapon, so I'd be fine with having the throw and catch be part of the same interaction with the object, for flashy fluff purposes.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Psionic Options Revisited *Unearthed Arcana* from April 14, 2020](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020_PsionicOptions.pdf), the Soulknife (Rogue subclass) gains the "Soul Blades" feature at 9th level, which has the following ability that does what you're asking for.

> **Psychic Teleportation.**
>
> If your Psionic Talent
> die is available, you can hurl your Psychic Blades to magically transport yourself to another location. As a bonus action, you manifest one of your Psychic Blades and throw
> it at an unoccupied space you can see, up to a number of feet away equal to 5 times the
> highest number on your Psionic Talent die. You then teleport to that space, the blade
> vanishes, and your Psionic Talent die decreases by one die size.

For reference, here is the 3rd level feature that initially describes the "Psychic Blades" mentioned in the Soul Blades feature:

> **Psychic Blades**
>
> *(3rd-level Soulknife feature)*
>
> You can manifest your psionic power as shimmering blades of psychic energy. When you are about to make a melee or ranged weapon attack against a creature, you can manifest a psychic blade from your free hand and make the attack with that blade. This magic blade is a simple melee weapon with the finesse and thrown properties. It has a normal range of 60 feet and no long range, and on a hit, it deals psychic damage equal to 1d6 plus the ability modifier you used for the attack roll. The blade vanishes immediately after it hits or misses its target, and it leaves no mark on its target if it deals damage.
>
> After you attack with the blade, you can make a melee or ranged weapon attack with a second psychic blade as a bonus action on the same turn, provided your other hand is free to create it. The damage die of this bonus attack is 1d4,
> instead of 1d6.

Comment: @NautArch part of the Soulknife's abilities detailed in the 3rd level feature let you manifest a Psychic Blade in a free hand as part of an attack you make. So while yes, the blade vanishes, you can immediately get it back if you then make an attack with your action (although it disappears again after the attack).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, you could multiclass. A way to achieve with the weapon would require you to be a Shadow monk or Shadow magic sorcerer but they can't really do it.  Even though Shadow monks and Shadow magic Sorcerers can cast darkness on their weapons and then teleport to them after they are thrown, they can't actually see the weapon/target they want to teleport to, so they are really forced to teleport to the edge of the darkness.

The best multiclass for this is actually Xanathar's Hex blade warlock.

Hex blades can get *Relentless Hex*, allowing you to teleport within 5ft of your hexed target if you can see them - I'd say that works best for this. It requires fewer levels to get, but the price is you can't really use hex a lot.

For the sake of your build though you might not want to multi class to go for any of this. I also wanted to warn you of the other problems with the shadow monk option.

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: I did an edit for organizational reasons. You had split up your two related bits about shadow monks/sorcerers, and I put them together to be followed by your recommendation for the hex blade.

Comment: It would also be good to quote the relevant rules to support your statements.